# compare array data with single column in database

Tags: php, sql

I need to check if the array stored data matches with the data present in the database. Meaning that, user will select check box data 1,4,5 which will be stored as `$data[]`. In database there is a table with a column `ID` which will have 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Every time user selects different check box, which will be stored in `$data`. I want to check those values with the database ID and i want to get only those values which is stored in-front of that ID in other column called 'value'

Example: if `$data` has value 3, 4, then it should get the value from the database only for 4 and 5.

I am not getting how to do this comparison and get the value.

```
$query = "select values from customer where bname = '".$_POST['bname']."' ";

$update = DB_query($query,$db);
while($row = DB_fetch_array($update))
{
    $array=explode(',',$row["values"]);
}
```

Comment: can you paste your code here?

Comment: Use "where in" clause in sql to select all selected value.

Comment: @senthilbp: I have posted my code

Comment: Try array_diff() .. hope it helps!!!

Comment: @sentilbp: thanks for your time. i used `in_array()` as suggested by Avin Varghese , it worked fine!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php  [array_diff();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) OR [in_array();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to compare array with your MySQL column.

```
  $query = "select values from customer where bname = '".$_POST['bname']."' ";

$update = DB_query($query,$db);
while($row = DB_fetch_array($update))
{
    $array=explode(',',$row["values"]);
}

    if (in_array("one", $array)) {
        echo "one Found";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Avin Varghese , It worked as i wanted!. Thanks a ton